# HashSet - ensuring the earlier object persistence

Tags: java, hash, collections, set, hashset

I have to use a `HashSet` where a lot of duplicate value may be inserted. But I want to preserve the earlier data inserted in the hash when a later insertion makes the duplicate. To examine this I have write the following code and insert many duplicate value, but it doesn't  satisfy me. Please see the code below -

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class SetTest {

    private static Set<Student> studentSet = new HashSet<Student>();
    private static Student s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9;

    public static void main(String args[]){

        s1 = new Student(1, 1, "Syeful", "first boy");
        s2 = new Student(2, 2, "Razib", "no comments");
        s3 = new Student(3, 3, "Bulbul", "should remain");
        s4 = new Student(4, 3, "Bulbul", "should not remain");
        s5 = new Student(5, 4, "Bulbul", "should remain");
        s9 = new Student(9, 5, "Proshanto", "kaka - my favourite");

        studentSet.add(s1);
        studentSet.add(s2);
        studentSet.add(s3);
        studentSet.add(s4);
        studentSet.add(s5);
        studentSet.add(s9);

        for(Student each : studentSet){
            System.out.println("SrNo: " +each.getSrNo()+ " roleNo: " 
                    +each.getRoleNo()+ " name: " +each.getName()+ 
                    " coment: " +each.getComment());
        }
    }

}

class Student{

    private int srNo;
    private int roleNo;
    private String name;
    private String comment;

    public Student(int srNo, int role, String name, String comment) {
        super();
        this.srNo = srNo;
        this.roleNo = role;
        this.name = name;
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + roleNo;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Student)) {
            return false;
        }
        Student other = (Student) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null) {
                return false;
            }
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (roleNo != other.roleNo) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int getSrNo() {
        return srNo;
    }

    public int getRoleNo() {
        return roleNo;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
Set Size: 5
SrNo: 9 roleNo: 5 name: Proshanto coment: kaka - my favourite
SrNo: 2 roleNo: 2 name: Razib coment: no comments
SrNo: 1 roleNo: 1 name: Syeful coment: first boy
SrNo: 5 roleNo: 4 name: Bulbul coment: should remain
SrNo: 3 roleNo: 3 name: Bulbul coment: should remain
```

It seems me to clarify some points before asking the questions so that I can explain it properly and clarify my understanding as well.

- I want to maintain the uniqueness of 'Student' based on `roleNo` and `name`.That's why the hashCode() and equals() role is made up with these property. So according to this implementation s3 and s4 are duplicate of each other even thought the `comment` , `srNo` property of them differs from each other.
- `HashSet` is unordered.
- When s4 is added in the set, we can see from the out put that s4 is discarded from the set and s3 remains.
- Suppose I want to add another object of student `s100 = new Student(3, 3, "Bulbul", "earlier instance suppressed");` which is the duplicate of s3. Let we have inserted a lot of duplicate of s3 before inserting s100.

**Question:**
Since set is unsorted and the duplicate dose not exist in set, is there any possibility that the s3 is removed by **s100**? I want to persist the earlier object discarding the later one. The small amount of data is not clarifying the fact. I think in this case a sorted `Set` may used. But does the `HashSet` can serve the purpose?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`HashSet.add(E e)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add(E)) leaves the set unchanged if it already contains the specified element. So, there are no circumstances where `s3` would be removed by `s100`.

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want collisions in your set, you need to redefine your hashing function to include more data in it, such as getSrNo. Relational Databases traditionally perform this using a unique primary key which is automatically generated for every new entry. This of "StudentID" or something like that, which should be unique across the school.