# Search Java ArrayList before inserting into it

Tags: java, search, arraylist

I have an ArrayList that is storing multiple objects that has 3 values: `title, fileName, tuthor`. I want to check if the value of fileName already exists before I add the object to the ArrayList.

```
PhotographArrayList photos = new PhotographArrayList();
Photograph photo;

photo = new Photograph();
photo.submitPhotograph("Enter photograph details: \n");

if(photos.find (photo.photoExist()) !=null)
    System.out.println("\nError: File already in use\n");
else
    photos.add(photo);
    break;
```

This is how I currently check if the photo fileName exists already and it calls this method from my `ArrayList` class

```
public Photograph find(String aEmail) {
    int index = id.indexOf(aEmail);
    if(index == -1)
        return null;
                else return photos.get(index);
}
```

However this code works but makes it hard to use Junit tests on the system, I want to find a way to get a `true` / `false` answer when searching if the `ArrayList` already has the value.

Sorry if its hard to understand my knowledge in Java is limited.

My arrayList class is:

```
public class PhotographArrayList {

    ArrayList<Photograph> photos;
    ArrayList<String> id;

    public PhotographArrayList() {
        photos = new ArrayList<Photograph>();
        id = new ArrayList<String>();
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return photos.size();
    }

    public void add(Photograph anPhoto) {
        photos.add(anPhoto);
        id.add(anPhoto.getAuthor());
    }

    public void print(String header) {
        for (int i=0; i<photos.size(); i++)
            System.out.println(photos.get(i));
    }

    public Photograph find(String aEmail) {
        int index = id.indexOf(aEmail);
        if(index == -1)
            return null;
        else return photos.get(index);
    }
```

Comment: What is "your ArrayList class"? You should rarely need to extend ArrayList.

Comment: If you want a "true/false" answer just change the return type to `boolean` and return `return id.indexOf(aEmail) != -1`

Comment: Override the `Photograph` `equals` (and `hashcode`) method so that they can be used to compare with another instance of `Photograph` and determine if their contents are "equal" or not

Comment: I added the arraylist to the original questions as the comments box is too small.

Comment: Why not use a `Set` instead where you can't have duplicates? And if you need it sorted, use a `TreeSet` specifically...

Answer (score 1):

You should use `Arraylist<Photograph>` instead of creating an specific class. Then you can override your `Photograph.equals` to check just the desired attribute, so the  `contains(Object)` method can do directly the check.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search by title of photograph and want that the photograph list will be unique by title then you can consider using `HashSet` where -

1. Override `equals()` method for `title` of the `Photograph` class.
2. Override the `hashCode()` method for the `title`
3. Crete a new `HashSet` of the photograph like -

   `Set<Photograph> photoGraphSet = new HashSet<PhotoGraph>();`

Now before adding any item to the `photoGraphSet` you can check whether the `photoGraphSet` contains any photograph of a given title like this -

```
Photograph aPhotograph = new Photograph("sample title");
if(!photoGraphSet.contains(aPhotograph)){
   photoGraphSet.add(aPhotograph);
}
```

Hope it will Help.
Thanks.

Comment: No need for the check, when adding, except for if, the `Set` already contains the item, maybe it should be updated. If the `Set` contains the item, the new item won't be added in the first place.

Comment: @Darwind, Suppose in some many `Photograph` has the same title but have different property like - `width`, `height`. In this case if once I add a `Photograph` to the `photographSet` with `title` - `t` and `width` 10. After that If I want to add an another `Photograph` to the `phototgraphSet` with `title` - `t` but `widht` 30. Then which `Photograph` will persist in the `photographSet`. Dose it always ensure that the earlier one inserted will persist? I'm not sure that's why I'm asking, don't take it other way. Thanks for your response.

Comment: In this context you may see the link too -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668814/hashset-ensuring-the-earlier-object-persistence

Comment: That's true - one will probably need to add a custom comparator to circumvent this issue, but right now your check `.contains()` won't do much good in the scenario you set up, because they'll never be same, if height or width are not the exact same values like the first photo. Maybe I'm misunderstanding you :-)
The `Set#add(E)` won't ever overwrite an item, if it exists though :-)